# Struts 2 - is there any way to escape HTML in input fields?

Tags: struts2

When I allow a user to enter text using `s:textfield`, he can enter something like `<b>Name</b>` or something like `\Me/`. I want that these should be escaped before I am saving them to the database. When we retrieve them, the escaping is done automatically, but I want it to happen also when we are saving it.

I was trying to return a `json` output from my action class, but due to a name `\a/` stored in my database, wrong json was being formed. This would have been avoided if the name had been escaped before being saved into the database.

Comment: Do you need more information in our answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html). You can call `escapeJavascript(textfield)` in your action and then store it into the database.

Comment: Additionally if its kind of input fields with perspective of user inputting HTML, i will go with simple HTML based text editor than relying on text-field

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi - i don't understand how 'simple HTML based text editor' can be a solution for storing esacaped text field

Comment: Can we add an interceptor that escapes every request parameter passed ?

Comment: @Daud: i was talking more about the UI perspective and you need to escape them for sure.Adding an interceptor for which take care for every request is not a good options,moreover the action specific data should not be handle in the Interceptors as that interceptors are not created for each request which can cause data issue

Comment: @Daud \@UmeshAwasthi I disagree, I think an interceptor for escaping parameters would be fine. It could be configured per-action with a list of parameters to make safe, or my reference, an annotation. You could also use a custom type convertor and configure that on the fields.

Comment: @DaveNewton:I was of impression about not playing with action specific data in interceptors,though configuring interceptor with parameter list was in my mind but i was not sure about data sanity.Thanks for correcting me

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Well... I'm still thinking about this one. One issue with transforming the parameters is that you then have to decide if you should transform them *back*, say on a validation error. Writing a blog post on some options now.

Comment: @DaveNewton:That's a valid scenario

Answer (score 1):

@Daud, The problem you explained is called ***Cross site scripting*** or XSS.
And I think you should use **Filters** to clean the request parameters. This is the most sophisticated way. You can call these filters for the actions which are posting some parameters via request.

Visit ***[my blog](http://jeevanpatil.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/prevention_of_xss/)*** to see how to avoid XSS threat using Filter approach.

I also faced this issue when our project was tested by well known firm specializing in security testing and they suggested this filter approach.

You can give it a try.